# How can I disable autocorrect in iOS 8 simulator at run time?

Tags: ios, selenium, appium

I am automating functional tests in the iOS 8 simulator with Appium (Selenium Driver). Unfortunately, when I attempt to enter text into a text field on a login screen, the sim automatically corrects my text causing a login failure. How can I disable autocorrect at run-time?

This program resets the simulator after each test, so any changes to the device settings would be wiped. I would prefer to not have to modify the app itself and I need to use iOS 8 (iOS 7 works).

Can you tell me if there is another way to set this capability in Appium or through Instruments? Or, perhaps another way to send text with Selenium?

Comment: I have tried the following without success: * Disabling Auto-Correct and Prediction from Settings. * Disabling Predictive text on Keyboard itself. Autocomplete still happens when I run my tests.

Comment: Resolved! I still turn off the autocrorrect and prediction from settings to be sure, but to bypass autocomplete for good, import the TouchAction library and use setValue() to set the value of the element directly instead of using sendText() to type each letter with keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

With open xcode you go on the storyboard. Do not select any view or table. Click on white. In the right corner you will in the first option and clear the "Use auto layout." Ready!

Comment: I would prefer not to change the app itself. The tests should mimic a user in the real app. Changing auto-layout may cause problems in other devices (iPad vs iPhone).